# Hardening Apache authentication to block brute force attacks (e.g. delay)

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ddos

Is there a way to configure Apache to slow down login after failed attempts?

It looks like it is not the default setting as already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806549/does-apache-basic-authentication-defend-brute-force-attacks).

On the other side it seems to be possible also without adding it to own application logic, on plain Apache, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522531/why-http-authentication-with-htaccess-get-slow-when-password-incorrect), but I found nothing in documentation and discussion???

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do it with a rule in the mod_security module:

```
SecFilterSelective VAR VALUE log,pass,pause:5000
```

But in the end you are better off using fail2ban or something like that to block the offending users.

Comment: I have the fear that installing any firewall module noticeable slows down the performance too much. Also the configuration of mod_security don't look like it's simple - anyhow, I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Its a pity, that there is nothing build in Apache for this simple login failure...

Comment: What firewall module? If you mean iptables doesn't have any noticeable overhead and fail2ban will protect you also against other kind of attacks (ssh).

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get this working. I have `mod_security2`, and it seems the syntax (and probably also the semantics) has changed. Surprisingly difficult to Google it up, too: only long screeds with lots of noise everywhere. Does a simple one-liner still exist for Apache (2.4 here) for this basic problem? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Fail2Ban can look for authentication error in error logs and block bf attempts with iptables